# Convert multiline in cell table to select option

Tags: php, html

My project is how to showing cell of table not in text, but in select option.

I have simple code:

```
<form method="post">
<textarea name="input"></textarea>
<button type="submit" name="button">button</button>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tableAll">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="col-md-1">name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['button']))
            {
                echo "<td>".$_POST["input"]."</td>";
            }
        ?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>

<style>
    td { white-space:pre }
</style>
```

I was input in textarea like this:

```
Andy
Alex
John
etc...
```

So, from input I want convert cell of table to select option in my page like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tableAll">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="col-md-1">name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <select>
            <option>Andy</option>
            <option>Alex</option>
            <option>John</option>
            <option>etc...</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["input"]))
    {
        $select_data = explode("\n",$_POST["input"]); // explode input data with new line
    }

?>
<?php if(count($select_data) >0){?>
    <select>
        <?php 
            foreach($select_data as $select_dat){?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $select_dat;?>"><?php echo $select_dat;?></option>
        <?php }?>
    </select>
<?php }?>
```